# How to store input's values between Routed pages with tab

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a react application which will contains dozens of screen for admin panel. I decided to open pages in tabs that integrated to react-router. When i change the current page and return back same page everything entered on inputs are being disappeared.

What is the best practice for this problem. It should be scaleable and must not require to write code in every page developed by a developer.

Also I use Redux for transferring userContext and appContext to every screen. Is Redux usable to store every input or other components' values?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create store for keeping input valus. You may update does valus on input changes and check if the store object has value on componentDidMount you can import values from store to inputs.

Comment: How? Should i write code for every input? I need something generic

Comment: Yes, you should write code for each input in this case. If you want generic solution, add onchange event listener to inputs. Use input name as store key and set the value and update the store.

Comment: I could not use input names cause they may not unique. Instead of using name, I generate a unique key for every input on run time.

Answer (score 0):

React state is good for storing data inside a component and even to pass it to its children. It is not ideal for passing data among siblings. This  is the exact case you have described above with dozens of components that do not share parent-child relationship.

The ideal solution for this problem is Redux. When you application state is stored in Redux, you can easily switch pages and not loose any data. Moreover, you can store the same Redux state in localStorage to prevent data loss due to browser refresh or shutdown. Lastly, if a need arises to persist your data in a database, fetch all the store values into props with mapStateToProps and pass them to backend.

Comment: Thank you Aditya. I couldn't find a example like you mentioned about. Do you know any example to give me?

Comment: A code sample over here would have been quite lengthy. So, I have created a small github repository to answer your question. It has a form split over two components. On second page, a call to DB can be made through axios.  Github Link: [https://github.com/addyrookie/ReduxForMultiPageForm](https://github.com/addyrookie/ReduxForMultiPageForm)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aditya. But this is not what i want. Lets assume someone developed insightC component that will be rendered on '/insightC. This component will include a input which does not aware of redux(calling action). How can i store this inputs value. I want something like this cause i can not force every developer to please do not forget bind your all inputs to redux!

Comment: Ok. You can ask developers to store input in sessionStorage or localStorage with key "component name". Then you can get data using sessionStorage or localStorage.getItem("Key").